# Mysql Join duplicates

Tags: mysql

i am curetly building a cms,
I have a tables called menus

```
Menus

MenuID | MenuName
1        Home
2        users
3        email
4        system
```

i have another table to control user access to these menus

```
call user_menu_access
MenuID | UserID
1           1
2           1
```

i am doing a left join like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM menus
LEFT JOIN user_menu_access 
    ON menus.MenuID = user_menu_access.MenuID 
WHERE UserID = 1
```

my result set dublicates rows as i will have to enties for 1 and 2  , i want to
have a result set that is as follows

```
MenuID  | UserID
1           1
2           1
3           NULL
4           NULL
```

Comment: what's wrong with your query? where are you having the duplicates?

Comment: manage to figure it out.SELECT * FROM menus M LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM user_menu_access   WHERE user_menu_access.UserID = '15' ) U
 ON (M.MenuID = U.MenuID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the condition into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT menus.menuid, userid 
FROM menus
LEFT JOIN user_menu_access 
    ON menus.MenuID = user_menu_access.MenuID 
    AND UserID = 1
```

See this query executing (giving exactly the results you asked for) [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a623e/2).

The reason this works is that the `WHERE` clause *filters* the rowset *after* the join has occurred, but because you're doing a `left join`, the columns of the `user_menu_access` table are all `null` for menus that don't have any user access, so your condition isn't true for those rows.

Comment: Why the downvote? This solution absolutely works. If you doubt this, see the link to sqlfiddle showing it actually working.